# Running script through shell_exec not giving the same output is when running on the server

Tags: php, bash, shell-exec

I'm having as issue with running a script using shell_exec in PHP.
When I log onto the server and run the script I get the correct output but when running it through the webpage it doesn't seem to be completing the commands.

The script is to use openssl to create .pem, .pfx and .p12 files from  .crt and .key files.

Bash Script is below:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Script to create all the SSL certs needed from the .key and .crt files

set -o errexit

echo "Starting script....<br><br>"
echo "openssl pkcs12 -export -in $1.crt -inkey $1.key -out $1.p12 -passout pass:$2"
openssl pkcs12 -export -in $1.crt -inkey $1.key -out $1.p12 -passout pass:$2
echo "P12 Complete.<br><br>"
openssl pkcs12 -in $1.p12 -nodes -out $1.pem -passin pass:$2 -passout pass:$2
echo "PEM Complete.<br><br>"
openssl pkcs12 -inkey $1.pem -in $1.crt -export -out $1.pfx -passout pass:$2
echo "PFX complete.<br><br>"
mkdir $1_certs
mv $1.key $1_certs/$1.key
mv $1.crt $1_certs/$1.crt
mv $1.pem $1_certs/$1.pem
mv $1.p12 $1_certs/$1.p12
mv $1.pfx $1_certs/$1.pfx
echo "Password: " $2 >> $1_certs/password.txt
echo "ZIPing files.<br><br>"
zip $1_certs.zip $1_certs
echo "COMPLETE<br><br>"
```

PHP is below:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['cert_name'])) {
$cert_name = $_GET['cert_name'];
$password = $_GET['password'];
echo "/home/<username>/ssl $cert_name $password <br><br>";
$message=shell_exec("/home/<username>/ssl $cert_name $password");
echo $message;
}
?>
```

The abundance of echo's in both was to aid in troubleshooting.

The webpage is a basic table with 2 inputs and a submit button.

When I Run this in the webpage it gets to the openssl command to create the .p12 and fails.

If I remove the `set -o errexit` so that it runs completely through regardless of errors I can see that it doesnt even try to create the directory or move the files, I just see all the echo's. Its as if it just runs the echos and ignores the commands.

I have an echo in before the command to create the p12 file and it shows that it is getting all the correct details.

I'm at a loss of where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like a permissions problem. When you run it from the shell, it runs as yourself. When the web server runs it, it runs as the web server's user.

Answer (score 0):

From the manual on [shell_exec](http://php.net/function.shell-exec#refsect1-function.shell-exec-returnvalues)

> ### Return Values
>
> The output from the executed command or `NULL` if an error occurred or the command produces no output.
>
> > #### Note:
> >
> > This function can return `NULL` both when an error occurs or the program produces no output. It is not possible to detect execution failures using this function. exec() should be used when access to the program exit code is required.

In debugging, `echo`, and `print`/`print_r` variations aren't very helpful, because they type cast `null` to a string. Instead you could use [var_dump](http://php.net/var-dump), which guarantees output for every input even if it is `null`.

---

As far as *why* it's failing there is a way to get back any information from `STDERR` by redirecting `STDERR` to `STDOUT`.

```
$message = shell_exec("/home/<username>/ssl $cert_name $password 2>&1");
```

It's also important to note that you should escape any arguments passed to the shell via [`escapeshellarg`](http://php.net/escapeshellarg)

If I had to guess at why it's failing my best guess would be that whatever user PHP is running under (if you're doing this via your web server, for example, and using Apache httpd with mod_php, it probably doesn't have the necessary permissions to execute `/home/<username>/ssl`. You should be able to determine that for sure by checking permissions on the file and confirming with `STDERR` information back from the shell.

Comment: Thanks for the help, using `var_dump` and `2>$1` enabled me to see that actual error message.
`string(115) "Error opening input file testing_ssl.crt testing_ssl.crt: No such file or directory unable to write 'random state' "`

Now for the fun of working out the issue.

Comment: You should use the absolute path to those files since the relative path could be undeterministic from a web context.